# Allow only text using jQuery in master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have created a label and textbox called signed by.

Here is my asp.net code:

```
<label>Signed By</label>
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSigned" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></div>
```

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#txtSigned").keypress(function(event){
 var inputValue = event.which;
 if(!(inputValue >= 65 && inputValue <= 120) && (inputValue != 32 && inputValue != 0)) { 
event.preventDefault(); 
}
});
```

So the user should enter text only in this textbox and numbers should not be allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `ClientID` for the `asp:TextBox` and on key pressed, check if it matches the regex specificed (only letters, upper- and lowercase) and possibly deny if not:

```
$("#<%=txtSigned.ClientID%>").on('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply urbz but I wanna implement it by jquery and master page as well so is it possible?